# What can I do when on a used computer I can not enter the administrator account?

Tags: passwd

I recently purchased a used computer, and the owner could not remember the administrater password. It has 13.04 on it.

Comment: can you help me

Comment: They may not really need to reset an admin password if they do not need to keep the data on the used machine. The answer linked to as dupe would be somewhat overkill IMO.

Comment: I'd make a fresh Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to revover a lost administrator password as outlined in this question:

- [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

However in your case you may not want to keep data or applications from the previous owner. In fact it may even be a security risk you will be faced when settings were made which possibly could give another person unlimited access to your machine.

Therefore the recommended and by far the easiest approach to your issue would be to just proceed with a fresh install of Ubuntu:

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)